# How to find recently updated values in hive without using time stamp

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a table like

```
id name sal 
1  Saa  45000
2  aaa  33000
```

after incremental load

```
id name sal
3  bbb  55000
```

How to get only recently updated value without time stamp

Comment: Take a backup before incremental load and subtract it after the incremental load.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way is using a partition. You can have a partitioned table and create a new partition every time you do the incremental load. This way the latest partition will only have the latest records.

Please be noted that very frequent incremental loads can lead to a lot of small partitions which may not be an optimum data design.

There can be couple other ways of doing this but that purely depends on what is your use case, the data rate, and volume.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Create a table.**

```
hive> create table student(id int, name string);
OK
Time taken: 3.503 seconds
```

**Insert one record into the table.**

```
hive> insert into student values(1, 'first');

hive> select * from student;
OK
1   first
Time taken: 0.109 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**Use below command on Hive terminal to find the location of the table. i.e meta store location of student table.**

```
hive> describe formatted student;

You should get the details as shown below.

# Detailed Table Information         
Database:               retaildb                 
Owner:                  root                     
CreateTime:             Thu Mar 08 15:52:47 PST 2018     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student
```

**Now Check the content**

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student
Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root supergroup          8 2018-03-08 15:53 hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/000000_0
[root@quickstart cloudera]# hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/*
1first
```

**Insert one more record.**

```
hive> select * from student;
OK
1   first
1   second
Time taken: 0.095 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

**Check the metastore location.**

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/
Found 2 items
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root supergroup          8 2018-03-08 15:53 hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root supergroup          9 2018-03-08 15:57 hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/000000_0_copy_1


[root@quickstart cloudera]# hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/000000_0_copy_1
1second
[root@quickstart cloudera]# hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/retaildb.db/student/*
1first
1second
```